# What is the maximum number of positive vectors such that a vector similar to only one of them can be found

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know what is $k^*$ the maximum $k$ such that:

$$
\exists z_1, \ldots, z_k \in\left(\mathbb{R}^+\right)^d \quad
\forall i \leqslant k \quad \exists \hat{z}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d \quad \hat{z}_i \cdot z_i>0 \quad and \quad \forall j \neq i \quad \hat{z}_i \cdot z_j<0
$$

($\cdot$ is the dot product here.)

Obviously $k^* \geq d$, but I have not been able to (dis)prove that $k^* = d$.
I have tried to prove it by an induction inspired from https://mathoverflow.net/a/31442/504480, but it hasn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: It is infinite if $d\ge 3$. Just put them on the boundary of a small aperture cone with the axis along the bisector of the quadrant.